# Why Kotlin compiler don't force me to initial my val defined in an interface?

Tags: kotlin

I wrote the following code in the IntelliJ IDE as a Kotlin program, and it unbelievably compiled and showed me a runtime error.

As you can see, the compiler forces me to override my `var` in the `Printer` class, but it didn't show any error for my `val`.

```
open class Printer(override var anString: String) : MyInterface

interface MyInterface {

    var anString: String

    val anInt: String
        get() = anInt + 50
}

fun main() {
    println(Printer("string").anInt)
}
```

Is this intentional or something?

This is my error when I run the code:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe"
> "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
> 2019.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=52595:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Work\IntelliJ\KotlinDataTypes\out\production\KotlinDataTypes;C:\Users\Neo\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:\Users\Neo\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;C:\Users\Neo\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-test.jar;C:\Users\Neo\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar;C:\Users\Neo\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar"
> com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.Test2Kt Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
> com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.MyInterface$DefaultImpls.getAnInt(Test2.kt:10)
>   at com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.Printer.getAnInt(Test2.kt:3)    at
> com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.MyInterface$DefaultImpls.getAnInt(Test2.kt:10)
>   at com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.Printer.getAnInt(Test2.kt:3)    at
> com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.MyInterface$DefaultImpls.getAnInt(Test2.kt:10)
>   at com.example.accessmodifiers.pack.Printer.getAnInt(Test2.kt:3)    at
> .
> .
> .
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thank you @4castle for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't show an error because have defined implementation for the `val` in the interface. Please keep in mind that whatever you define in an interface is `abstract` unless you define a concrete implementation, which in your case of `val`, you did it through `get()` custom accessor. Also, another point to note that if you don't use `field` keyword to set/get your implementation, your program will crash because of a recursive function. For example:

```
get() = field + 50
```

Saying `anInt + 50`, is recursive because the moment you call `anInt` val, it will call it's `get()` under the hood, that also calls another `get()` and so on.

If you have already provided concrete implementation in an abstract class or an interface, the compiler will not force you to override that behaviour but will force you to implement that lack concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `anInt` declaration is incorrect. It will cause stack overflow error and returns the wrong type.

The compiler doesn't show any error because you provided default behavior for `anInt`. If you, for example, remove `anInt` getter, the compiler will force you to declare overridden property in `Printer`